# How to upload image with Rest in Drupal 8.3?

Tags: rest, drupal

I want to upload image to Drupal server via Rest. I found a post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-send-files-to-drupal-8-via-rest and follow the instructions in the answer.  But a error message was recieved: "message": "A fatal error occurred: Field _links is unknown.". Anyone know how to get it done in Drupal 8.3? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

follow instructions here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2682341#comment-11965256
additionally add the X-CSRF-Token to the header as well. I tested this on 8.3.2

one thing I noticed is that images are in "Temporary" status, I'm not yet too familiar with the API but one workaround for this is to change the file status in the file_managed table in the database...